# Auto baking the indirect lighting of irradiance volumes with animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

I've searched forums, Google, and YouTube for a way to use Eevee's  irradiance volumes with animation (moving objects), and haven't found any solutions, or even a mention of this. Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms.

In short, when using irradiance volumes and Eevee, indirect lighting doesn't recalculate between animation frames when it's baked, and it doesn't render at all when it's not baked. Checking 'Auto Bake' in the Indirect Lighting tab seems to only have an effect when I manually change the settings on an irradiance volume.

Can irradiance volumes be used with moving objects?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not yet supported with moving objects (e.g. animated mesh lights).

Answer (score 0):

According to Blender at 
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/indirect_lighting.html in paragraph 3:

> As of now the light cache is static and needs to be computed before rendering. It cannot be updated per frame (unless via scripting). This limitation is being worked on and will be removed in future versions.

Comment: Do you know if this is exposed to the Python API? I'd definitely write an add on to do this, but I can't find the documentation.

Comment: Same, i need to render animation with a screen emitting light each frame, and i believed auto bake would work but it doesn't update each frames

Comment: Now 2023 and Blender 3.6 still has not added this simple feature, when should we expect the "limitation" will be removed? Or is there another reason this is not being added?